# HandlebarsJS pass helper to another helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have two helpers, one called tablerows and another called svg-icon. I want to pass the result of svg-icon into tablerows. svg-icon returns a Handlebars.SafeString of HTML. How can I achieve this? I saw something called a subexpression but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
   {{#tablerows section="Highlights" }}{{/tablerows}}
   {{#svg-icon symbol=symbol.value size="small" class="svg-icon--table" }}{{/svg-icon}}
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve but no success:

```
    {{#tablerows section="Highlights" {{#svg-icon symbol=symbol.value size="small" class="svg-icon--table" }}{{/svg-icon}} }}
{{/tablerows}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking your helpers as if they are [Block Helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html), by using the `#` symbol, however there is no need for them to be Block Helpers as there is nothing between the opening and closing tags.

If we instead use these helpers as [regular](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers), non-block, helpers, then we will be able to make use of [subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) in order to pass the result of the `svg-icon` helper to the `tablerows` helper:

```
{{tablerows (svg-icon symbol=symbol.value size="small" class="svg-icon--table") section="Highlights"}}
```

Note: This assumes that the `tablerows` helper has been defined to accept an HTML string, as is returned by `svg-icon`, as its first parameter:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('tablerows', function (iconHtml, options) {
    /* Helper body goes here. */
});
```